Successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative vlaue (-1) in Ubuntu 22.04
I have recently purchased RTX3060 cuda complaint GPU.
I was able to update drivers , install cuda toolkit and install tensorflow with GPU .
While checking the avalaibility of GPU in tensorflow, I cam across the following messages
>>> with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
...     a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
...     b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
...     c = tf.matmul(a, b)
... 
I0000 00:00:1722448721.476212    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
I0000 00:00:1722448721.477842    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
I0000 00:00:1722448721.478043    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
I0000 00:00:1722448721.556155    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
I0000 00:00:1722448721.556352    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
I0000 00:00:1722448721.556507    7976 cuda_executor.cc:1015] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-07-31 23:28:41.556635: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2021] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10001 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6


How bad would be performance degradation because of this issue ?
How do I supress the non critical error warning message ?
What I Tried:

Successfully installed CUDA drivers, CUDA toolkit, and TensorFlow with GPU support.

Verified GPU availability using tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU').


What I Expected:
TensorFlow to smoothly utilize your RTX 3060 GPU.
What Happened:
TensorFlow detected the GPU but encountered NUMA-related warnings.
